# How to pass array variables to parallel matrix in GitLab CI pipeline?

Tags: pytest, gitlab-ci, pipeline

Trying to configure parallel testing. Is there some way to set up a variable as an array and use it in matrix? For example:

```
stages:
- test

variables:
  SUITES: $SUITES

test:
  stage: test
  image: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - SUITE: [$SUITES]
  script:
    - pytest -m ${SUITE} --json-report --json-report-file=${SUITE}_report.json
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - "${SUITE}_report.json"
    expire_in: "1 day"
```

The case is to run jobs in parallel with suite and artifacts for each job. Maybe, I'm looking the wrong place?

Answer (score 1):

The variable expansion within the `parallel` keyword is currently unsupported. There's an open [issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/11549) regarding this feature request.

To work around this limitation, you can use a method that involves `envsubst`, a `template file`, and a `trigger using artifacts`.

```yaml
# .gitlab-ci.yml
stages:
  - process

variables:
  SUITES: '["suite1", "suite2", "suite3"]'

template:process:
  stage: process
  before_script:
    - apt-get update
    - apt-get install gettext-base
  script:
    - envsubst '${SUITES}' < template.yml > template.suites.yml
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - template.suites.yml

template:trigger:
  stage: process
  trigger:
    include: 
      - artifact: template.suites.yml
        job: template:process
    forward:
      pipeline_variables: true
  needs:
    - job: template:process
```

The `template.yml` file should be present within your repository:

```yaml
# template.yml
stages:
  - test

test:
  stage: test
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - SUITE: ${SUITES}
  script:
    - pytest -m ${SUITE} --json-report --json-report-file=${SUITE}_report.json
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - "${SUITE}_report.json"
    expire_in: "1 day"
```

The final pipeline looks like this
[image]

Hope this helps. ‍

Answer (score -1):

See the GitLab docs on the [`parallel:matrix`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#parallelmatrix) keyword. The whole idea is to set up multiple variable definitions which will each be run in parallel. Each list element in parallel will be one job specification; list elements should be dictionaries specifying the variables to be set in each job.

In your case:

```yaml
test:
  stage: test
  image: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE
  parallel:
    matrix:
    - SUITE: endpoints
    - SUITE: smoke
    - SUITE: auth
  script:
    - pytest -m ${SUITE} --json-report --json-report-file=${SUITE}_report.json
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - "${SUITE}_report.json"
    expire_in: "1 day"
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply!

I actually need to pass SUITE Variable as an array like this:
  SUITES: $SUITE
I was incorrect in my question, sorry

Comment: why? can you please modify your question to include the full context, including how/when the value of SUITE will be set? is SUITE a project or group variable, or is it being passed in from a trigger project, etc? the context matters

Comment: I have a similar use case where the variable of the matrix (here SUITE) should be read from a variable $SUITES set from a former job in my pipeline. \
So I have also something like \
- SUITE: [$SUITES] \
but my job do NOT explode the strings there.

Comment: if you have a new question please create a new post, don't add it as a comment to this answer. see [ask]